# Is there any .world library?

Tags: gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have a simple question, is there a world library somewhere ?

I know https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src but I feel like a world sharing tool would offer worlds of minimum 400m2 populated by models than focusing on a precise definition of a single model.

[This question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18666/is-there-any-libraries-of-world-environment-in-sdf-version-14/) makes me believe that there should be one somewhere but I cannot find it.

Thanks for any help
TTDM,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19072/is-there-any-.world-library-?/) by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Several worlds are installed together with Gazebo. You can see the list here:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/worlds/

Any of these worlds can be loaded from any directory by pre-pending `worlds`, for example:

`gazebo worlds/empty_sky.world`

[IgnitionFuel.org](https://IgnitionFuel.org) currently only supports models, but it will also support worlds in the near future.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on 2018-04-20**:
I should have added your first link in my question since I already launched all the worlds inside this directory to see what was available, my bad. Your second link, however, does answer my question. Great to see this project coming directly from the foundation! If i may, it could be put in the spotlights so that people contribute more to it : in the main page of the gazebo website,there is a link: Useful Link/simulation Model which lead to the list of models, on top of this page a few words ...

**Comment by [TTDM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3017/ttdm/) on 2018-04-20**:
linking to IgnitionFuel could be added. Or even better, in the main page, the link could be "Simulation Model and Worlds" which would open a page with quick links to either the model directory,  the world directory and ignition fuel. The 3 links being complementary :model for the quality of each of its components, worlds because opening all the world is, to my experience, a great way to discover some gazebo features and ignition fuel for all the non official, community contributed ressrouces!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-04-20**:
Thank you for the suggestions :) I'll bring them up with the team.